# String trim functions with destination size limitation

Tags: c, strings

> 3 string trimming functions:
>   Trim whitespace from the beginning of a string.
>   Trim whitespace from the end of a string.
>   Trim whitespace from both ends of a string.

Looking to improve code for:

1. Correctness (tested code - but so far no holes) - especially overlapping src/dest cases.
2. Design
3. Portability (3 tried: MS, *nix, embedded)
4. Efficiency

Note: `(unsigned char)` used as unless `x==EOF`, `isspace(x)` is not defined when `x < 0`.

```
/* String trim functions
 * 
 * Result is sized limited.
 * Overlapping source and destination is OK.
 * Pointer parameters are assumed to point to valid strings spaces.
 */

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

// Return string beginning with first non-white-space in string `src`
// Return NULL when destination is too small, `dest` unchanged.

char *trim_begin(char *dest, size_t dest_size, const char *src) {
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *src)) {
    src++;
  }
  size_t src_size = strlen(src) + 1;
  if (src_size > dest_size) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return memmove(dest, src, src_size);
}

// Return string beginning string `src` but not including any of its trailing 
//   white-spaces.
// Return NULL when destination is too small, `dest` unchanged.

char *trim_end(char *dest, size_t dest_size, const char *src) {
  size_t len = strlen(src);
  while (len > 0 && isspace((unsigned char) src[len - 1])) {
    len--;
  }
  size_t src_size = len + 1;
  if (src_size > dest_size) {
    return NULL;
  }
  memmove(dest, src, len);
  dest[len] = 0;
  return dest;
}

// Return string beginning with first non-white-space in string `src` but not 
//   including any of its trailing white-spaces.
// Return NULL when destination is too small, `dest` unchanged.

char *trim(char *dest, size_t dest_size, const char *src) {
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *src)) {
    src++;
  }
  return trim_end(dest, dest_size, src);
}
```

Comment: Use character constants for readability: `dest[len] = 0;` -> `dest[len] = '\0';`

Comment: @chqrlie Agreed [Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16956451/2410359)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me.

A couple of (very) minor points: you should say in the comments that src mustn't be NULL; you don't need src_size in trim_end if you use the test 'if (len>=dest_size)'.

Comment: "should say in the comments that src mustn't be NULL".  OK - though about that before-hand.  In multiple places, comments say "Trim whitespace from   ... a string" and " string `src`",   Thought that was sufficient to imply `src` must be a pointer to a string ("contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character.") and not `NULL`.  Yet begin explicit may help.

Comment: I suppose some might think that since there are no characters, therefore no spaces, in a NULL string, it would be safe to trim it and you'd get NULL back, which might be better behaviour than a crash.

Comment: Adding a well behaved `trim(NULL)` is a interesting idea and I generally favor it.  Yet standard string functions like `strcat(ptr, NULL)`, `strcmp(NULL, NULL)` do not include defined behavior and I was following that model.

Answer (score 4):

- **Repeated code**

  ```
  size_t src_size = strlen(src) + 1;
  if (src_size > dest_size) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return memmove(dest, src, src_size);
  ```

  is a good candidate for a function (`safe_memmove` or something similar).

<s>- **Optimistic loops** `while (isspace((unsigned char) *src))` may never stop: `'\0'` is *not* a white space. Test for end of string explicitly:</s>

```
    while (*src && isspace((unsigned char) *src))
```

Red face above. I don't know what I was thinking.

- **Portability**. A free-standing environment doesn't have to provide `memmove` or `strlen` or `isspace`. Only features confined in `<float.h>, <iso646.h>, <limits.h>, <stdarg.h>, <stdbool.h>, <stddef.h>, and <stdint.h>` are mandatory. I am afraid that to claim *embedded* portability you need to implement optional features yourself.

  Sorry for nitpicking.

Comment: If `'\0'` is not a white space, then `while (isspace(*src))` will end when it reaches the `'\0'`.  So I don't understand the "Optimistic loops" objection.

Comment: @JS1 You are absolutely correct. I don't understand it either.